# While updating database from package console manager getting this error Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

While updating database from package console manager getting this error Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code should get name of connection string from appsettings, not its value.

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) 

it gives me this error now

Comment: in Appsettings servername should be computer name?

Comment: @MajidQureshi connection string should point to your SQL server, if it is hosted locally then you can use localhost or 127.0.0.1 also